# Login page that uses .htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I've been trying to make a login page with HTML and JS which uses my `.htaccess` files to access a website instead of having that ugly pop up window with the user:pass.

I've got this code so far, which doesn't work. When I put in the username and pass, all it does is redirect to the page and opens its .htaccess

```
<form name="login-form" class="login-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="server" value="mywebsite.com/private">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Develop Page</h1>
        <span>Login to access!</span>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" />
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>       
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <input type="button" class="button" onClick="Login(this.form)">Login</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

And the JS:

```
<script>
function Login(form) {
    var username = form.username.value;
    var password = form.password.value;
    var server = form.server.value;
    if (username && password && server) {
        var htsite = "http://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server;
        window.location = htsite;
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter your username and password.");
    }
}
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this?
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The `"http://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server` format does not work on IE since IE9 I believe, supposedly for security reasons. I don't think there is a way to accomplish this well, short of changing how the server does authentication (e.g. custom user/session management/redirects/etc.). There are many user/session management libraries out there that might help you.